# Cumulocity Inventory API filter by Creation Date

Tags: cumulocity

I'm currently trying to implement a simple date filter for the Inventory API using the query language. The filter should return a list of managed objects which were created after a given date. For some reasons I always receive an empty list as result but the example in the [query language documentation](https://www.cumulocity.com/guides/reference/inventory/#query-language) looks the same as my query:

```
GET {{url}}/inventory/managedObjects?query=creationTime+gt+'2018-12-01T09:00:53.351Z'
```

gives me

```
{
"managedObjects": [],
"next": "{{url}}/inventory/managedObjects?query=creationTime+gt+'2018-12-01T09:00:53.351Z'&pageSize=5&currentPage=2",
"statistics": {
    "currentPage": 1,
    "pageSize": 5
},
"self": "{{url}}/inventory/managedObjects?query=creationTime+gt+'2018-12-01T09:00:53.351Z'&pageSize=5&currentPage=1"
}
```

And if I try this structure for the timestamp I even receive an error:

```
GET {{url}}/inventory/managedObjects?query=creationTime+gt+'2018-12-01T09:00:53.3512B1:00'

{
"error": "inventory/Invalid Data",
"info": "https://www.cumulocity.com/guides/reference-guide/#error_reporting",
"message": "Find by filter query failed : Query 'creationTime gt '2018-12-01T09:00:00'' could not be understood. Please try again."
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to filter by

```
creationTime.date
```

Background is that the timestamps are stored as MongoDb dates.
You can also check the device list filter in device management which has a filter on creationTime as well.